# Change Int Value Inside the While Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, integer, return-value

I try to make snake game and I want increase score when snake eat the food I have a int score upper the game loop and I want the increase in the while loop to the score and I get a error Segmentation fault (core dumped).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

#include <list> 

int main()
{
    
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "omega");
    sf::Event ev;
    
// tail 
    
    std::list<int> tail;
    
//shape 
    
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(18.f, 18.f));
    sf::RectangleShape tailRectangle(sf::Vector2f(18.f, 18.f));
    sf::RectangleShape foodRectangle(sf::Vector2(18.f, 18.f));
    
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color(250, 250, 250));
    tailRectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color(250, 250, 250));
    foodRectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 0, 0));
    
// variable
    
    int x = 80.f;
    int y = 80.f;
    
    int speed = 4;
    int FLAG = 0;
    
    std::string direction = "down";
    
//Time
    
    sf::Clock clock;
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    
// Food
    
    int foodChoice_x;
    int foodChoice_y;
    int score = 3;
    
    bool foodFlag = true;
    
//Game loop
    
    while (window.isOpen())

    {
        
        // FPS 
        float currentTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        float fps = 1.0f / (currentTime);
        
        //Event polling
        while (window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            switch (ev.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    if (ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                        window.close();
                    
                    if (ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W)
                        FLAG = 0;
                    if (ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S)
                        FLAG = 1;
                    if (ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                        FLAG = 2;
                    if (ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                        FLAG = 3;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        
// Eat Food 
        if (foodChoice_x * 20 == x && foodChoice_y * 20 == y)
        {
            score++;
            foodFlag = true;
        }
// Food maker
        if (foodFlag)
        {
            foodChoice_x = rand() % 17 + 2;
            foodChoice_y = rand() % 17 + 2;
            
            foodRectangle.setPosition(foodChoice_x * 20, foodChoice_y * 20);
            foodFlag = false;
        }
        
// Tail maker
        
        int count = 0;
        
        if (x % 20 == 0 && y % 20 == 0)
        {
            tail.push_front(x);
            tail.push_front(y);
        }
        
        if (tail.size() > score * 2)
            for (int n : tail)
            {
                tail.pop_back();
            }
        
        if (FLAG == 0)
            if (x % 20 == 0 && y % 20 == 0)
                direction = "up";
        if (FLAG == 1)
            if (x % 20 == 0 && y % 20 == 0)
                direction = "down";
        if (FLAG == 2)
            if (x % 20 == 0 && y % 20 == 0)
                direction = "left";
        if (FLAG == 3)
            if (x % 20 == 0 && y % 20 == 0)
                direction = "right";
        
        if (direction == "up")
            y -= speed;
        if (direction == "down")
            y += speed;
        if (direction == "right")
            x += speed;
        if (direction == "left")
            x -= speed;
        
//Update
        
        rectangle.setPosition(x, y);
        std::list<int>::iterator it = tail.begin();
        
//Render
        
        window.clear(); // Clear old frame
        
//Draw your game 
        
        window.draw(rectangle);
        window.draw(foodRectangle);
        
// Draw tail 
        
        count = 0;
        int X;
        int Y;
        
        for (int n : tail)
        {
            
            if (count % 2 == 1)
                X = n;
            if (count % 2 == 0)
                Y = n;
            
            count++;
            
            if (count % 2 == 0)
                tailRectangle.setPosition(X, Y);
            window.draw(tailRectangle);
        }
        
//FPS
        
        window.display(); // Tek app that window is done drawing
        
//End of application
        
// Food eat 
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I except the value increase and not get a error but that's not working but when I put the declaration score in the while loop that s working but useless because value is same every time.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to include one.

Comment: mb should I delete the post

Comment: Don't delete it, [edit] it...

Comment: Or just edit it and include your code as text and formatted instead of as an image.

Comment: I edit may bad sorry everyone.

Comment: Groovy. Much better. I'm going to tweak the indentation a bit.

Comment: A note about `std::list`. It's almost always a doubly linked list, and they can be deadly slow if you do more iterating than inserting and removing. Insert and rermove can also be deadly slow if you don't already know where the location is  because... More iterating.

Comment: Good that you edited – the image didn't show anything suspicious, but *this* piece of code *is*: `for (int n:tail) { tail.pop_back(); }` – as a std::list it might not invalidate the `end` iterator, but if it does you get UB. Why don't you just `tail.clear()`?

Comment: thank you again i will pay attention the iterating.

Comment: I now that reason ı started 3 the score. When ı delete the score the program is working well.

Comment: because if ı clear the tail nothing appear it is the tail have to be some cordinate insedi the tail.

Comment: String comparisons are slow, too – and unnecessary here. Instead of setting a direction string and check it afterwards just do the respective action on *determining* the direction: `if(flag == ...) { if(x && y) { var += or -= speed }`. And as soon as `flag` already compares equal to one value it cannot again for another one, so add `else`s to your code: `if(flag == 0) { } else if(flag == 1) { } ...` – even better: use a `switch` statement, this can be implemented as a jump table and typically is faster.

Comment: How many nodes would you want to retain in the tail? If just the head, then you could do `tail.erase(std::next(tail.begin()), tail.end())` instead – or `std::next(tail.begin(), n)` for retaining the first *n* nodes (but make sure there *are* n nodes in the list, otherwise UB again).

Comment: Off-topic, but you should avoid all capitalised identifiers (`FLAG`), these usually indicate *macros*.

Comment: sure I fix that :o I thought flag is important.

Comment: It probably is important, but the ALLCAPS macro warning is a time-honored tradition. An unexpected macro substitution can really ruin your day, so it's good to throw a bone to your code's future users so they know what's coming But in this case nothing is coming, and that'll lead to funny looks cast in your direction.

Comment: O.T.: Concerning `int x = 80.f;`: `80.f` is a floating point constant -> type `float`. The compiler will silently convert it to `int` but it's a bit misleading (as if you intend to store numbers with fractions in `x` - which is impossible). Just `int x = 80;` is cleaner. (And the same for `int y = 80.f;`, of course.)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).